# Commerce - Alter quanitity widget

Tags: commerce, navigation

I'm new to commerce and I have a question. I'm building a website for a butcher, and he wants products to be sold per 100gr. I have the price in kilo and I allow decimal values for quantity.

The quantity field widget is a text box by default. I did some googling and found some things but i'm unable to get it work. I assume I need the commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form() function :)

I want to have a drop down with pre-defined values per 100 gram for example.

---

100 gram - 1 euro
200 gram - 2 euro
300 gram - 3 euro
....

### 1000 gram - 10 euro

Add to cart button

Any idea's? Or is there an easyer solution for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you allow decimal in the quantity field, you can use the [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) hook. It is one of the most used drupal hooks.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  // add to cart form
  if (strpos($form_id, 'commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_') === 0) {

    // Replace the text quantity field with a select list.
    if (isset($form['quantity']) && ($form['quantity']['#type'] == 'textfield')) {

      $product = commerce_product_load($form['product_id']['#value']);
      $price = commerce_product_calculate_sell_price($product);

      $select = array(
        '0.1' => '100grams '.commerce_currency_format(1*$price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
        '0.2' => '200grams '.commerce_currency_format(2*$price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
        '0.3' => '300grams '.commerce_currency_format(3*$price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
        '0.4' => '400grams '.commerce_currency_format(4*$price['amount'], $price['currency_code'], $product),
      );

      $form['quantity']['#type'] = 'select';
      $form['quantity']['#options'] = $select;
      $form['quantity']['#size'] = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks, this is what i'm looking for, however can the price be dynamical too? Like based on the price field, and that I get my calculation result in the array?

Comment: @J.Minnebo I have updated the code. It is not tested but I think it will work

Comment: Hello, the code worked indeed! I'm probably going to have another product which will have be sold as per unit. Where can I specify that this code should be used for product line x and the other code (which I can re-use from yours) for product line y? Also how do I extend this to work on the cart page? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check the $product->type variable if this is a product type x or y.
If the answer helped you, you can accept it and/or vote up.